# How to set multiple belongsTo relations for a model in Loopback?

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopbackjs

I have 3 models: "Companies," "Employees," and "Employments." The "Employments" model should have a `belongsTo` relationship with both a company and an employee, and inversely every "Employee" should have a `hasOne` relationship with an "Employment," and each "Company" should have a `hasMany` relationship with "Employment."

However, I can't get this working. I have tried to do this:

```
1  employee.employment.create({role: 1});
2
3  employee.employment((_, employment) => {
4      employment.employer(company);
5
6      resolve();
7  });
```

To no avail. The `create()` on line 1 works great––as in, I can query the `employee/${id}/employment` endpoint just fine––but my attempt to connect it to the employer on line 4 is not being persisted.

Based on [the docs](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/BelongsTo-relations.html), which say

> order.customer(customer); Set the customer for the order

it seems like line 4 should persist that relationship. Could this be a bug with Loopback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, looks like this is all I had to do:

```
Employment.create({
    role,
    employerId: employer.id,
    employerType: employerModel,
    employeeId: employee.id
});
```